# Mysql Regexp character at any position AND at the first position

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I search using 'VW' I need a mysql regexp pattern that finds just VOLKSWAGEN and NOT VOLKSWAGEN and VOLVO.

I try first:

```
SELECT title FROM brand WHERE title REGEXP '^[VW]'
```

So I get all records with `V` at the first position.

I do not know how to combine the conditions `V` at the **FIRST** character and `W` at **ANY** position.

I try :

```
SELECT title FROM brand WHERE title REGEXP '^[VW]' AND title REGEXP '[VW]'
```

And also tryied with Having clause

```
SELECT title FROM brand WHERE title REGEXP '[VW]' HAVING title REGEXP '^[VW]'
```

I know we have separate alternatives would we have a kind of `&&` condition for REGEXP ?

Thank´s in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a regexp for this.  You can just use `like`:

```
where title like 'V%W%'
```

The advantage of `like` is that MySQL can use an index on `title` to partially satisfy this (because the patter starts with a constant).

Answer (score 2):

```
^V[a-zA-Z0-9]*W
```

Try this.This should get you words staring `V` and having `W` somewhere.